# Check if something is before time

Tags: php, time

I wanted to do something like where:

```
$time = time();
//Store the time in the dabase

//Some time later, say three hours this code runs
// so if your time() was 2pm its now 5pm when this statement
// is run.
if($time < 4 hours){
    // do something.
}
```

But I am not sure what the cleanest way to do this is.

Comment: 4 hours from now? 4 hours from the fall of the Roman Empire? Before 4am? Your question needs a little more context.

Comment: First you need to give value to `hours` as in `$hours = "";`

Comment: i think he mean 4 hours before now

Comment: Updated. hope that explains things better

Comment: Do you mean if the current time is more than 4 hours from the saved `$time`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOP-style

```
$start = new DateTime;

// Do something

if ($start < new DateTime('-4 hours')) {
    // Do something different
}
```

http://php.net/datetime

The non-OOP way is also simple

```
$start = time();

// Do something

if ($start < strtotime('-4 hours')) {
    // Do something different
}
```

http://php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 1):

time() is going to give you back the php time in seconds. when your second block of code runs you want to check the time() again, so you should do something like this:

```
$timeNow = time();
if($savedTime < $timeNow-14400){
    // do something
}
```

where 14400 is 4 hours (60*60*4 == 14400) in seconds. Of course there may not be a reason to set time() to a variable, but just in case.